# Changing strings to ints in .csv in r

Tags: r

I am writing a code in r where I need to load in a .csv and convert string columns to ints.

For example: I have a column that reads "83", "42", "64", how do I convert their types to ints so I'm left with 83, 42, 64?

Thanks

Comment: Use `as.numeric()`

Answer (score 2):

I would leave this as a comment, but I can't as I don't have enough rep... If you read the documentation to [read.csv](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html), you will find that there is a parameter called `colClasses` where you can specify the class of your csv as it is being read in.

For example, if you are reading in `myFile.csv` and the you want the first column to be read in as integer, you would do:

```
read.csv("myFile.csv", colClasses = c("integer", .... ))
```

Alternatively, you can easily coerce any column by using the respective `as.` functions (e.g. `as.integer`, `as.numeric`, etc.)

```
myDF <- read.csv("myFile.csv", colClasses = "character", stringsAsFactor = FALSE) ## all columns will be character
myDF$V1 <- as.integer(myDF$V1)
.
.  ## coerce more columns here
.
```